# Добавление товара в корзину React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Я начинающий в React'e, мне нужно что бы по нажатию добавлялся товар в корзину.

Товара пока 3:

[image: тестовый вариант]

Тестовый вариант без какого либо стиля:

[image: код]

Comment: Текстовую информацию (код) нужно добавлять в вопрос в виде текста, а не в виде скриншотов.

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример как это можно сделать с помощи хука [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html):

```
const PCart = () => {     
    const initialState = {
      cartData: {
         priceData: [
           {id: 1, priced: 20, desc: "Шампанское"},
           {id: 2, priced: 10, desc: "Вода"}
         ] 
      }
    }
    
    const [state, setState] = useState(initialState)
    
    const onItemAddHandler = () => {
      setState(prevSate => ({
        ...prevState,  
        priceData: [
           ...prevState.priceData,
           // сюда разместите Ваш объект с данными
           // ниже мой mock
           {id: 3, priced: 1, desc: "Спички"}
        ]
      }))
    }

    return <button onClick={onItemAddHandler} value="Купить:" />
}
```